# Compartir carpetas entre sitios de servidores windows

Tags: iis, windows-server, activedirectory, lan

Tengo dos servidores windows en la misma LAN, ambos con el mismo sitio en el IIS, pero necesito que solo uno almacene los archivos estaticos (por ejemplo las fotos), como puedo hacer para desde el servidor B, tenga una carpeta "Imagenes", que las consume desde el servidor A

- Servidor A => tiene una carpeta Imagenes con archivos
- Servidor B => tiene una carpeta Imagenes con los archivos del servidor A

Comment: has probado usar FTP?

Comment: ¿Has provado a usar dfs?